# What is the preferred IUPAC name of 4-propionyl biphenyl?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, aromatic-compounds

Is the IUPAC name of the following compound 4-propionyl biphenyl?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compound that is given in the question is a ketone. According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*, the preferred names for ketones derived from alkanes are constructed using the suffix ‘one’.

Furthermore, the selection of a preferred parent structure is based on the seniority of classes, which gives priority first to characteristic groups expressed as suffixes and then to parent hydrides when different classes are present.

Therefore, the preferred parent structure for the compound given in the question is ‘propan-1-one’.

The parent structure is substituted with a ring assembly R at the first carbon atom. Thus, the resulting name is ‘1-(R)propan-1-one’, where the name R of the ring assembly is determined as follows.

[image: 1-(R)propan-1-one]

Generally, according to the current IUPAC Recommendations, ring assemblies of two identical cyclic systems with a single bond junction can be named by one of two methods:

> (1) by placing the prefix ‘bi’ (…) before the name of the corresponding parent hydride enclosed in parentheses, if necessary. Parentheses are used to avoid confusion with von Baeyer names;
>
> (2) by placing the prefix ‘bi’ (…) before the name of the corresponding substituent group (…), enclosed in parentheses, if necessary.

For the unsubstituted parent structure of the given ring assembly, the traditional name ‘biphenyl’ is retained.

With regard to numbering of locants, the current version of the IUPAC Recommendations reads as follows:

> Each cyclic system is numbered in the traditional way, one with unprimed locants, the other with primed locants. Lowest possible locants must be used to denote the positions of attachment. These locants must be cited in preferred IUPAC names; they can be omitted in general nomenclature when no ambiguity would result.

Therefore, the preferred IUPAC name (PIN) of the unsubstituted structure of the given ring assembly is ‘1,1'-biphenyl’ and the locants ‘1,1'’ are compulsory. (The name ‘biphenyl’, without locants, may be used in general nomenclature.)

[image: 1,1'-biphenyl]

Concerning substituent prefixes derived from such ring assemblies, the current IUPAC recommendations read:

> Names of substituent groups derived from ring assemblies are written in two ways:
>
> (1) the suffix ‘yl’ is added to the name biphenyl;
>
> (2) names denoted by locants are placed in brackets; the suffixes ‘yl’ and ‘ylidene’ are added with elision of the final letter ‘e’ in the name of the parent hydride.

Low locants are first assigned to ring junctions (here: ‘1,1'-’), then to free valences (here: ‘4-yl’).

Therefore, the complete name of the compound given in the question is **1-([1,1'-biphenyl]-4-yl)propan-1-one**.

[image: 1-([1,1'-biphenyl]-4-yl)propan-1-one]